# jquery fading multiple divs with different timings

Tags: jquery, fade, setinterval

am converting a flash animation to jquery#

i basically have a load of divs which are different colours, i want to the divs to fade in and out, each div has a different timing based on a fibonachi sequence,

i am having problems assigning a fade function to the div, i want the fade function to fade out the div then when is completed fade it in again, and keep repeating the process for each div.

here is my current code but it crashes firefox presumably to do with me having so many `setintervals` can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
var myDiv ='#bannerHolder'
    var fib_str = '1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13'
    var widths_str = '33px, 31px, 35px, 9px, 16px, 50px, 33px, 24px, 40px, 20px, 63px, 30px, 10px, 29px, 11px, 12px, 51px, 31px, 35px, 11px, 14px, 50px, 30px, 25px, 38px, 20px, 35px'
    var pos_str = '0px, 44px, 105px, 144px, 153px, 203px, 236px, 269px, 280px, 354px, 374px, 437px, 447px, 457px, 506px, 517px, 529px, 604px, 646px, 687px, 698px, 712px, 762px, 787px, 823px, 895px, 915px'
    var color_str = '#D5E1D7, #18D4C9,#BF51C3,#1E82C9, #EDEDED, #E1C981, #C9A94F, #BDBCAA, #5DB522, #EB2F34, #823133, #004BD8, #A6A0A0, #DS9F36, #FFDB00, #69944F, #18D4C9, #BF51C3, #1E82C9, #6B949A, #FFDB00, #819E64, #BDBCAA, #54BA43, #EB2F34, #823133'
    var width = widths_str.split(",");
    var pos = pos_str.split(",");
    var color = color_str.split(",");
    var fib = fib_str.split(",");
    console.log(width);
    console.log(pos);
    console.log(color);
    var counter = width.length
    var stopper = false;
          for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
        var html = '<div id ="stripe'+i+'"/>'   
        $(myDiv).append(html)
        $('#stripe'+i).css({  'top': 0,  'left': pos[i],'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'background-color' : color[i]})
        $('#stripe'+i).attr({'height': 100, 'width': width[i], 'min-width' : width[i], 'min-height' : '100px'  })
        $('#stripe'+i).width(width[i])
        $('#stripe'+i).height('100px')
        var myfibtime = (fib[i] * 200);
        setInterval(stripeFadeOut(i), myfibtime );
                setInterval(stripeFadeIn(i), myfibtime );
    };
    function stripeFadeOut(id){
        $('#stripe'+id).fadeOut('slow');
        var myfibtime = (fib[id] * 200);
    }
    function stripeFadeIn(id){
        $('#stripe'+id).fadeIn('slow');
        var myfibtime = (fib[id] * 200);
    }

})
```

if i use `setInterval('stripeFadeIn(' + id + ')', myfibtime+'`; i get stripeFadeIn is undefined, if i try to use .animate as suguested by mathew i get too much recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating interval object in your loop as well as in your setFadeIn function that causes creating interval objects exponentially. Ultimately ends up by crashing browser.

Instead you can do one thing in the loop itself, create two intervals i.e one for fadeOut and one for fadeIn. Insted of 'slow', use some milliseconds of your choice.

Then your fadeOut should be called on every myfibtime + animatingMilliseconds = fadeOutInterval. And your fadeIn should be called on every fadeOutInterval + animatingMilliseconds.

I hope this will help you

My suggestion completely refers to your old code. So do like this

```
for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
        var html = '<div id ="stripe'+i+'"/>'   
        $(myDiv).append(html)
        $('#stripe'+i).css({  'top': 0,  'left': pos[i],'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'background-color' : color[i]})
        $('#stripe'+i).attr({'height': 100, 'width': width[i], 'min-width' : width[i], 'min-height' : '100px'  })
        $('#stripe'+i).width(width[i])
        $('#stripe'+i).height('100px')
        var myfibtime = (fib[i] * 200);
        var animTime = 1500;
        var fadeOutInterval = myfibtime + animTime;
        var fadeInInterval = fadeOutInterval  + animTime;
        setInterval(stripeFadeOut(i), fadeOutInterval );
        setInterval(stripeFadeIn(i), fadeInInterval );
    };
    function stripeFadeOut(id){
        $('#stripe'+id).fadeOut(1500);            
    }
    function stripeFadeIn(id){
        $('#stripe'+id).fadeIn(1500);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but am a bit lost now, i had changed the code in my question to reflext mathews suguestion of usinhg .animate() with a :complete param, so i dont know if you are talking about the original code or the updated code, some sample code would be really helpfull i'm getting nowhere on this :(
I have updated my question to remove the code suguested by mathew as the .animate method causes too much recursion

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking into jQuery animations http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and setup a callback to do the opposite fade.

Their example uses opacity for the animation, so perhaps that will give you the desired effect.

Comment: hi thanks mathew ive edited the code to use animate but am getting a too many recursions error see my changed code in the question

Comment: One problem I see with your code is setTimeOut(stripeFadeIn(id), myfibtime ); calls stripFadeIn immediately.  You should do setTimeout('stripeFadeIn(' + id + ')', myfibtime);

Comment: The problem you're having is because you're actually calling the function instead of defining a callback.

Comment: sorry mathew i am more stupid than you realise, i have 3 functions, one which starts the fading and 2 more, to fadein and fade out the div, which one needs the call back?
I have updated the question again so you can see the current code i have...

Comment: and i still think that the .animate is not going to work, as i dont want this animation to stop, i want it to keep looping, so the script will always break with a too many recursions error

Comment: The `animate()` method accepts a callback for when the animation complete.  You simply need to have the callback repeat the animation.

Comment: @matt: i have a callback on the `.animate()` call, the callback on the `stripeFadeOut()` function calls `stripeFadeIn()` and that calls `stripeFadeOut()` but with this method the script breaks with too much recursion (which is what i want because i dont want this animation to stop) if this is bad then whats the best way to achive the looping of the fading in / fading out???

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen your updated code. I have a feeling you're doing it wrong.

Comment: The problem in your code, is when you're calling setInterval (or specifiying a callback) you're inadvertently calling the function instead.

eg: testMethod(myCallback());
is different than testMethod(function(){myCallback();});